# PowerShell - Find duplicate file inside ZIPs and CABs

Tags: powershell

I am trying to write a script that will find duplicate file inside a compressed files.
The compressed files can be ZIP or CAB (Need help to extract CAB file also because currently its not working).
What I have so far is to extract the zips to a temp folder (don't know how to extract cab) and if there is a vip inside I need to extract him also to the same folder. currently all the files are extracted to the same temp folder what I need is to extract each zip/cab into a folder with the original name even if he has a vip inside. (the zip/cab are not flat) in the next step I need to find duplication files and display all the duplication and where they found.
The script below is not working...

```
$tempFolder = Join-Path ([IO.Path]::GetTempPath()) (New-GUID).ToString('n')
$compressedfiles = Get-ChildItem -path C:\Intel\* -Include "*.zip","*.CAB"

foreach ($file in $compressedfiles) {   
        if ($file -like "*.zip") {
            $zip = [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::ExtractToDirectory($file, $tempFolder)
            $test = Get-ChildItem -path $tempFolder\* -Include "*.vip" 
       
            if ($test) {
                $zip = [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::ExtractToDirectory($test, $tempFolder)

            }
      }
}

$Files=gci -File -Recurse -path $tempFolder | Select-Object -property FullName

$MatchedSourceFiles=@()
ForEach ($SourceFile in $Files)
{
  $MatchingFiles=@()
  $MatchingFiles=$Files |Where-Object {$_.name -eq $SourceFile.name}
  
  if ($MatchingFiles.Count -gt 0)
  {
    $NewObject=[pscustomobject][ordered]@{
      File=$SourceFile.FullName
      #MatchingFiles=$MatchingFiles
    }
    $MatchedSourceFiles+=$NewObject
  }
}
$MatchedSourceFiles

Remove-Item $tempFolder -Force -Recurse
```

Comment: Please add an error message or describe _exactly_ what is not working. What is the actual and what is the expected output?

Comment: Why would you extract the files when you can read them directly?

Comment: Hi
There is no error message, I cannot extract the compressed files with there original names, Don't know how to handle CAB files. in addition the script cannot return if there are duplicate files and where exactly

Comment: Why would you extract the files when you can read them directly? 
Because I don't know how to do that . This is why I am asking here
Thanks

Comment: [This past answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71634519/15339544) shows how to read a zip recursively, you just need to readapt it

Comment: Its not the same. It was my question..
I don't know how to convert it to this case, and compare the files and also need to handle with cab
I am asking for help and maybe someone can help with that. If I had the answer I would not ask.

Comment: Can I get any help with that? Please

Answer (score 1):

Building on what you have already tried, you could do this like:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.IO.Compression.FileSystem

$tempFolder      = Join-Path -Path ([IO.Path]::GetTempPath()) -ChildPath (New-GUID).Guid
$compressedfiles = Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Intel' -Include '*.zip','*.CAB' -File -Recurse

$MatchedSourceFiles = foreach ($file in $compressedfiles) {
    switch ($file.Extension) {
        '.zip' {
            # the destination folder should NOT already exist here
            $null = [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::ExtractToDirectory($file.FullName, $tempFolder)
            Get-ChildItem -Path $tempFolder -Filter '*.vip' -File -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
                $null = [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::ExtractToDirectory($_.FullName, $tempFolder)
            }
        }
        '.cab' {
            # the destination folder MUST exist for expanding .cab files
            $null = New-Item -Path $tempFolder -ItemType Directory -Force
            expand.exe $file.FullName -F:* $tempFolder > $null
        }
    }
    # now see if there are files with duplicate names
    Get-ChildItem -Path $tempFolder -File -Recurse | Group-Object Name | 
    Where-Object { $_.Count -gt 1 } | ForEach-Object { 
        foreach ($item in $_.Group) {
            # output objects to be collected in $MatchedSourceFiles
            [PsCustomObject]@{
                SourceArchive = $file.FullName
                DuplicateFile = '.{0}' -f $item.FullName.Substring($tempFolder.Length)  # relative path
            }
        }
    }

    # delete the temporary folder
    $tempFolder | Remove-Item -Force -Recurse
}

# display on screen
$MatchedSourceFiles

# save as CSV file
$MatchedSourceFiles | Export-Csv -Path 'X:\DuplicateFiles.csv' -UseCulture -NoTypeInformation
```

The output would be something like this:

```
SourceArchive    DuplicateFile          
-------------    -------------          
D:\Test\test.cab .\test\CA2P30.BA0      
D:\Test\test.cab .\test\dupes\CA2P30.BA0
D:\Test\test.zip .\test\CA2P3K.DAT      
D:\Test\test.zip .\test\dupes\CA2P3K.DAT
D:\Test\test.zip .\test\CA2P60.BA0      
D:\Test\test.zip .\test\dupes\CA2P60.BA0
```

Comment: Thank you very much Theo. I am trying it right now, Most of the times there is no vip inside the zip (msi files). Your solution cover it also? maybe need to add this case?
I have tried it with zip that has msi file inside 2 subfolders (level 2)

Comment: I have tried the cab and its working :).
Question: If one cab holds 3 duplicate files for example, I will get 3 results. there is an option to compare only in several cabs/zips? I want to know if there any duplication in a bulk of compressed files (if one have more then 1 it count as 1)

Comment: @Bandit. you are now asking two new questions on top of this one in comments, so I won't go into that. The question you posted has now been answered by me

Comment: Theo, it’s still the same question. As I wrote the zip includes files and if it included vip I need to extract him also. Please try to add it for me

Comment: Please help me with that please, most of the time the zip contains files but need to handle vip also, 

Comment: @Bandit ... Please have a look at the part where it unzips .zip files. Immediately after doing that if tries to find .vip files and extracts these too..

Comment: regarding this I will open a new question
I have tried the cab and its working :). Question: If one cab holds 3 duplicate files for example, I will get 3 results. there is an option to compare only in several cabs/zips? I want to know if there any duplication in a bulk of compressed files (if one have more then 1 it count as 1)

Comment: Theo, There is a problem with the sourcearchive, it show always only one file, also in the output that you provided although there are duplication results
I have 2 zips with the same file inside and the SourceArchive show me only one zip file name

Comment: Sorry but its not working as expected. I have 2 zip files with the same xml file inside and I don't get duplication results

Comment: @Bandit No, because your question (and your own code as well) was about duplicate filenames inside the **same** .zip or .cab file.

Comment: definitely not
The goal is to compare between many compressed files
Can you fix it for me please?